# How to pass param between ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass param between two different ajax calls, the params only exist inside the ajax scope but not outside of it.

i saw the option of calling from the first ajax success section to another ajax and i don't want this, is their any other way?

my code

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: '/modules/products/ajax.php',
  data: {
    prod_id: prod_id,
    act: 'get_selected_values_for_sub_cat'
  },
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {

    var res = JSON.stringify(data);
    res = jQuery.parseJSON(res);

    var selected_array = [];
    jQuery.each(res, function(key1, value1) {

      selected_array[key1] = jQuery.parseJSON(value1);
    })

  }

});

console.info("selected_array", selected_array);
```

i try this

```
function ajax_get_selected_values_for_sub_cat() {
  return jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/modules/products/ajax.php',
    data: {
      prod_id: 123,
      act: 'get_selected_values_for_sub_cat'
    },
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

    }

  });
}

var re = ajax_get_selected_values_for_sub_cat();
res = JSON.stringify(re);
res = jQuery.parseJSON(res);

var selected_array = [];
jQuery.each(res, function(key1, value1) {

  selected_array[key1] = jQuery.parseJSON(value1);
})
console.info("selected_array", selected_array);
```

what am i missing ?

thanks

Comment: You can do this using promises

Comment: why cant you use a temporary public variable?

Comment: No, there's no other way. You can't start the rest of the code until the ajax is complete, so there must be a callback involved. You can reduce the nesting using promises, but it's still going to involve callbacks.

Comment: I can't follow your code - where is the second ajax call and what is the data it needs to be able t see

Comment: Simon H the second call is irrelevant because it doesn't even print the console.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax function returns an object that implements the promise interface.   You can implement it like this:

```
    function ajax_get_selected_values_for_sub_cat(id) {
      return jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/modules/products/ajax.php',
        data: {
          prod_id: id,
          act: 'get_selected_values_for_sub_cat'
        },
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json'
      });
    }

    var promise = ajax_get_selected_values_for_sub_cat(123);
    promise.done(function(re){
        res = JSON.stringify(re);
        res = jQuery.parseJSON(res);

        var selected_array = [];
        jQuery.each(res, function(key1, value1) {

          selected_array[key1] = jQuery.parseJSON(value1);
        })
        console.info("selected_array", selected_array);
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback methods as below-

```js
function ajax_get_selected_values_for_sub_cat(successCallback) 
        {          
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : '/modules/products/ajax.php',
                data : {prod_id:123,act:'get_selected_values_for_sub_cat'},
                type : 'POST',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data){
   successCallback(data);
                }

            });
        }

ajax_get_selected_values_for_sub_cat(function(re){
            res =JSON.stringify(re);
            res  = jQuery.parseJSON(res);

            var selected_array =[];
            jQuery.each( res, function( key1, value1 ) {

                selected_array[key1]=jQuery.parseJSON(value1);  
            })
            console.info("selected_array",selected_array);
});
```